# Cookie not recognized when switched domain between app services

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I'm going to move sso server application (ASP.NET CORE DOTNET 6) from app service APS1 located in service plan AP1 to new app service APS2 located in different service plan APS2 (can't use Change service plan due to azure restriction on regions and resoruce groups). I cloned sso app from APS1 to APS2, added certificate and switch custom domain from APS1 to APS2. So after the change we have the same application, but located in another app service plan and another app service, under excatly the same domain. What I'm trying to understand is why cookie issued by app located in APS1 is not accpted by the same application, moved to APS2 under exactly the same domain which was switched from APS1. I tried to perform the same operation using sample app from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0 but with the same results - cookie is not being recognized after switching domain from APS1 to APS2.

Answer (score 0):

What helped was to set the same application name with:

builder.Services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("appName");